# add service reference not generating specified field for optional value type

Tags: wcf, visual-studio, service-reference, xsd.exe

I have the following in an xsd -

```
 <xsd:complexType name="isPermissableRq_Type">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="accNr" type="ObjectId_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xsd:element name="bankNr" type="BankNr_Type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="BankNr_Type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:long">
      <xsd:totalDigits value="10"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
```

Generated reference -

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName="isPermissableRq", WrapperNamespace="http://contracts.co.za/TransactionMgmnt", IsWrapped=true)]
public partial class isPermissableRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageHeaderAttribute(Namespace="http://contracts.co.za/Infrastructure/2008/09/EnterpriseContext")]
    public Services.Svc2014.EnterpriseContext_Type EnterpriseContext;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://contracts.co.za/services/2014-12-16/TransactionMgmnt", Order=0)]
    public string accNr;

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://contracts.co.za/services/2014-12-16/TransactionMgmnt", Order=1)]
    public long bankNr;


    public isPermissableRequest() {
    }

    public isPermissableRequest(Services.Svc2014.EnterpriseContext_Type EnterpriseContext, string accNr, long bankNr) {
        this.EnterpriseContext = EnterpriseContext;
        this.accNr= accNr;
        this.bankNr = bankNr;
    }
}
```

When I add a service reference using vs 2013, i expect a specified field to be generated for bankNr, since minOccurs is 0, but that does not happen. Any ideas? This field needs to accept a null.

Comment: Try to add `xs:nillable="true"`

Comment: @LukasKubis is there no way of getting minOccurs=0 to work? thats our standard

Comment: I'm not sure. Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758549/xsd-exe-doesnt-enforce-minoccurs)

Comment: @LukasKubis Hmm, I saw that. I would have expected it to work though. Those 3 scenarios are met- it is an element, maxOccurs is set to 1 and the data type converts to a value type

Comment: Please show us how the generated class looks like

Comment: @LukasKubis updated with the code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62833/discussion-between-lukas-kubis-and-newbie-86).